# Imagick how to avoid half visible text

Tags: php, imagick

I am rendering some text that has multiple lines.
I have a defined height for the text, e.g. 200px.

First I use ImagickDraw to draw the text and at the end
I crop the drawn Image to the specified height.

Everything works as expected but the result is not really ideal.

The problem is I get lines of text that are half visible in height.

[image]

My question is, is there any way to avoid this, to crop the image only between the lines of text?

Answer (score 0):

You need to measure your text height using i.e. [queryFontMetrics()](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.queryfontmetrics.php), and having that you can tell where to crop, or what canvas size needs to be to fit all the texts you want to put there.